# How to add a text block side by side with image and have margins

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I am new and learning html. For now using Dreamweaver to help me out. I am trying to put an image right next to a text box. I made a container which contains 2 columns side by side. on the left column i entered the text and the right side i put the image. Everything works fine, but i want to change the alignment of the text so to put a margin/gap on the left side. But doing this pushes the image down. I cant seem to figure out how to maybe make the image smaller for the text to fit or how to get this to work? I tried floating to left, set display to flex but still not getting what i need. Here is my html and css:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="col-lg-6"><img src="images/banner1.jpg" width="770" height="415" alt=""/></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

```
@charset "utf-8";
.container .row .col-lg-6 {
    margin-left: 20px;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First a few remarks which may be useful**

1. The selector `.container .row .col-lg-6`, which you used for setting the margin to your text, selects both columns, as they share the same class name. In this case, you might want to avoid this, as you're only targeting the text.
2. It's often a good idea to set your [box-sizing property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to border-box for all elements: `box-sizing: border-box;`. This will make it easier to control the position of your elements, without having to make calculations for taking the padding, border or margin into account.
3. Also remember that div's are [block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) by default. This means they will take up the full available width, and display one after another, like a column. You could change this behavior by setting their display property to inline-block (`display: inline-block;`).
4. Try to use responsive units whenever possible. By hard coding your image's dimensions in pixels, you're making it harder to make your page responsive.

**This could be your new code**

```css
@charset "utf-8";

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* the selector below selects BOTH columns */
/* .container .row .col-lg-6 {  
  margin-left: 20px;  
} */

.column-1 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 30vw;
}

.column-2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50vw;
}

.column-2 img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 column-1">
        Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
        fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae,
        ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam
        egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend
        leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum
        erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean
        fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci,
        sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar
        facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor
        neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat
        volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis
        luctus, metus&nbsp;
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 column-2">
        <img
          src="https://picsum.photos/600/400"
          alt=""
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**BUT**: I strongly recommend you take a look at other layout models in CSS, like [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) or [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout). This will make your life much easier.

**Quick example with flex**

```css
@charset "utf-8";

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex; /* makes this element a flex container, and its child elements flex items */
  justify-content: space-evenly; /* distributes available space evenly between the flex items */
  align-items: center; /* aligns the flex items vertically */
}

.flex-item-1 {
  width: 30vw;
}

.flex-item-2 {
  width: 50vw;
}

.flex-item-2 img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="flex-item-1">
        Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
        fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae,
        ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam
        egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend
        leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum
        erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean
        fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci,
        sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar
        facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor
        neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat
        volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis
        luctus, metus&nbsp;
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item-2">
        <img
          src="https://picsum.photos/600/400"
          alt=""
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```